# "An unhandled non-continuable exception was thrown during process load"

Tags: windows, winapi

This error message appears on a colleague's machine when he tries to launch a Windows application he's working on:

> An unhandled non-continuable exception was thrown during process load

What does this mean, and how does one go about investigating what is causing it?

I have Googled it, but haven't found a clear answer.  It seems to have something to do with problems loading DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there more information in the error message, maybe in the debug console?  If there's a stack trace available, it might point you to the problem application, or better yet, the DLL that's causing the problem.  The next step would be to see if there's an update available for that DLL.

Comment: Please check same problem not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384773/how-to-make-gtk-work-on-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 2):

Right I'm looking over this issue in my own code at the moment - for anyone who is having this issue, here's some pointers:

1. There is a fairly involved thread discussing it here: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/555706-unhandled-non-continuable-exception-thrown-during-process-load
2. Are you linking to Winmm.lib? It's got problems, can you avoid using it?
3. Are you using C++/CLI? If so, consider delay loading the C++/CLI module.

Any other hints, please post - this crops up from time to time and can be problematic!

More details are on: http://www.dwmkerr.com/post/2012/02/08/Debugger-An-unhandled-non-continuable-exception-was-thrown-during-process-load.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found that enabling the "Read&Execute" permission on a dll that was checked in to version control solved this problem.

The first thing I tried was to copy my whole Debug/ directory somewhere and the app ran fine there, then I checked the properties of each of the original dlls and enabled execute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out that a DLL compiled for x64 in a x86 project was the culprit. Replacing the DLL with the x86 version resolved the issue.